# Multiple wall switch wiring issue

Tags: wiring, switch

[image]

I am replacing wall switches and unfortunately did not label the wiring before removing. I also changed 2 outlets that were switched on the bottom and always live on top to always live.

Wires 2W & 2B when tested are live and are switched by the Living Room Breaker.

Wires 5W & 5B are live and controlled by the Front light and time clock Breaker. Time clock is for driveway lights.

Wires 3W & 3B when connected to 2W & 2B allow all Living room outlets to work correctly.

Wires 4W, 4R (Red), and 4B, I currently do not know if or where these need to be connected.

Wires 1W and 1B, if I turn of breaker and connect white & black wires together that lead to porch light then I can read that I have a complete circuit with a ohm meter when testing across 1W & 1B.

Now my problem...If I connect 5W & 5B to 1W & 1B, I believe I should get my porch light. My porch light is a motion sensing light and only clicks and doesn't turn on but my driveway lights will work but pulse off every second or two. I disconnected porch light and the driveway lights do not work at all. I hooked another light to porch wiring and the light did not work but the driveway lights do work without pulsing. The light I tried was a direct wire ceiling light.

I originally had 3 switches. 1 for driveway lights, 1 for porch light, and 1 for living room outlets that I no longer need.

I believe/thought that 4W, 4R (Red) and 4B was wiring for the switched outlets that I changed to not switched.

Help, I need to figure out how to wire the switch for the porch light and then also a switch for the driveway lights.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Were any of the switches 3-way switches?

Comment: No 3 way switches. Have since connected wires 1 & 2 and the porch light will work but no driveway lights. Starting to think that #4 wires might be driveway lights and the outlet on the post. Suggestions?

Comment: Well I don't think the #4 wires are driveway. I connected the #4 wires to the #5 wires and no lights. I think the #4 wires are to the switched outlets that have been converted to always on. At the moment, I don't think I need the #4 wires hooked up. Now I am wondering if the #5 wires are actually switched between them from the timer? Can I test the theory by connecting the #5 wires together with a wire nut? Think they then lead back to the timer and then out to the driveway lights. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM RESOLVED! #5 was a switch connection from the timer. #1 was porch lights. #2 was main feed. #3 was living room outlets and #4 was no longer used